# Different values on metrics between API and Interface

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Someone please help me ... I am using this code to fetch from the api all the pages under a certain dir with pageviews and unique visitors.
With the api i get 109 visitors and 233 pageviews for 2023-08-13 but in Analytics for the same day it's more then double ... 222 uniques with 640 pageviews.

Same url 100% ... any ideas ? Thank you in advance.

```
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'pageSize' => '20000',
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2023-08-13',
            'end_date' => '2023-08-13',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'pagePath',
        ]
    ),
    ],
    'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression([
      'filter' => new Filter([
        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
        'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
          'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH,
          'value' => '/url-here/',
         ])
      ])
    ]),
    'metrics' => [
    new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers'
        ]
    ),
    new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'screenPageViews'
        ]
    )
    ]
]);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that data api and explorations rely on different datasets, as mentioned on the Google Analytics Help docs found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9371379?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article:%7E:text=Related%20resources-,Reports%20and%20explorations%20support%20different%20fields,you%20different%20views%20of%20your%20data%2C%20at%20different%20levels%20of%20granularity,-.%20For%20example%2C%20some)
ga data api runReport method rely on report's datasets, while explorations seems to be querying different dataset.